# What does Storm really bring to the table?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

First off, I'm sorry if this is a bad question; I admit to only recently getting into the X-Men comics, after watching the movies.

Don't get me wrong, along with most of the X-Men, Storm's mutant powers are impressive. However, given the large number of mutants in the X-Men universe, it seems that Professor Xavier could certainly do much better. Storm really doesn't fit in with the team very well.

Are her abilities really so extraordinary they justify her presence at the forefront of the X-Men adventures? Does she actually provide other benefits?

Comment: A better question is why Scott is on the team since his powers are basically just a glorified gun.

Comment: “Storm really doesn't fit in with the team very well” — yeah, Charles should really slot in another great team player, like Wolverine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Storm brings a lot to the table. No, seriously. Lots.

Firstly, ignoring her powers, remember Xavier's primary aim is to keep mutants safe and educate them. Not just educate them about the world but also the world at large and foster good human-mutant relations. Ororo was an orphan and then worshipped as a god when Xavier first found her and took her in.

She is noted as being:

> ... *one of the strongest willed* among the X-Men, making her *highly resistant to psychic attacks*, especially in tandem with electrical fields she creates around herself. Telepaths have found it difficult to track her down and probe her thoughts. Several of these traits are independent of her mutant status and are a result of her ancestry.

She is an expert pick-lock and thief, and has training in martial arts and handgun use. She has defeated mutants such as Callisto (superhuman reflexes and a healing factor) and Crimson Commando (cyborg), using her superior strategic knowledge. Storm is also fluent in Russian, Arabic and Swahili. Oh, and she can [see in the dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfi8e.jpg).

To top it off she is from a line of witches; in an alternate universe she became a sorceress of considerable power.

She's a worthy member of his team even without her mutant abilities, and has led the team *sans power* for a short while, after having defeated Cyclops. (Who, by the way, shoots lasers out of his eyes. She defeated him. Without her powers.)

Talking of her [control of weather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_%28Marvel_Comics%29#Weather_control), it provides attack, defence, stealth and transport capabilities which are noted to be at an *insanely* powerful level, with some sentinels considering her an [Omega-Level mutant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-level_mutant#Omega-level_mutants).

<sub>Sources: [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_%28Marvel_Comics%29)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to "vote it up" but apparently I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: She's also very nice and makes friends and allies easily. A natural leader.

Comment: Great synopsis. Very thorough answer.

Answer (score 7):

While I actually am not that familiar with X-Men, I can answer this question in a more general way that is applicable to any hero group: It's just as much about a person's willingness to be a hero as it is with their abilities. Storm is willing to go out there and put her life at risk to fight for what she believes in. You can be the most powerful person in the world, but if you are not willing to put your life on the line, you are not a hero. Xavier, with his ability to read minds, is well aware of the thoughts of his team... no matter what abilities a mutant has, they must have the mindset of a hero.

Obviously, Storm does. If she's good enough for Xavier, she's good enough for me.

Comment: Fantastic PoV :D

Answer (score 1):

Storm provides more than just her powers, leadership and the voice of reason when the "heavy hitters" start approaching the line of questionable actions.  Since joining the X-men she has always ended up on the side of either Leader or first officer in the group.  Plus the ability to call lightning down on an enemy in any universe is still pretty cool.